# Twitter button event when already following

Tags: javascript, twitter

I have a Twitter follow button embedded on a page. My question is how can I trigger a javascript function on load when the button indicates that they are already following? I see the follow event in the docs here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tfw/events , but I do not see any events for when a user is already following. I've tried accessing the iframe content with no success due to cross domain access control. Any suggestions?